# Unable to authenticate Bitbucket with Jenkins, get Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

Using Jenkins,Pipelines,Blue Ocean and Bitbucket

I have the following Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'f2c1e487-2df0-4ed9-ec25-56d8622615db', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:comapny/tooldata.git']]])
    }
  }

  stage('Test') {
    steps {
      bat 'e:\\test.bat test'
        }
  }
 }
}
```

which results in the following error

```
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:company/tooldata.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:company/tooldata.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:company/tooldata.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:825)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1092)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:273)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:company/tooldata.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The credentialsId I refer to appears to have been accepted within Jenks, so now I am at a loss.

Comment: I believe `git@bitbucket` is used with SSH connections. That's why you get `stderr: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).`. Try HTTP method instead. Unless you're using SSH private key. I'm not much familiar with Jenkins.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm sorta hitting this issue myself

Comment: Eman, sorry, no.